Get rendered HTML block template from Post
I'm not new to WordPress but I have a question for the gutenberg api.
I want to get a single post by id with the rendered post template for this ID. But I don't know how to archieve this problem because the codex has not that information for me.
So when I request the https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1 I got a not the default post template block rendered content html but the post_content rendered content.
So my question is how can I access the detail element (single view) from a custom post type rendered in HTML. So we in classic themes i can easily get this rendered content with get_template_part and the ID of the post.
So how can I access the rendered html content for a single view from a post.

To achieve the desired results you need to create a custom REST API endpoint that returns the rendered post.
In order to create custom REST API endpoint please add the given code to your theme's functions.php file or in a custom plugin.

    function get_rendered_post_template_data($data) {
        $post_id = $data['id'];
        $post    = get_post($post_id);
    
        if ( !$post ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'no_post', 'Post not found', array('status' => 404) );
        }
    
        setup_postdata($post);
    
        ob_start();
        // Here you can adjust the template part if you have specific ones for different post types
        get_template_part('single', $post->post_type);
        $rendered_html = ob_get_clean();
    
        wp_reset_postdata();
    
        return array(
            'id'      => $post_id,
            'title'   => get_the_title($post),
            'content' => $rendered_html,
        );
    }
    
    function register_custom_routes() {
        register_rest_route( 'custom/v1', '/rendered-post-data/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
            'methods'  => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'get_rendered_post_template_data',
        ));
    }
    
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_custom_routes' );


We can access the rendered post by making a GET request to the custom endpoint we have created.
For example, if your site is https://domain-name then it should be accessed by using https://domain-name/wp-json/custom/v1/rendered-post-data/1

Thanks, but this is only working for classic themes not for block themes. The get_template_part is not working with block themes. This was already tried by me.

Could you please try to check with the given code.
$rendered_html = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
instead of get_template_part

If you want full link you can get that with the help of wp_remote_get.
$web_link = get_permalink( $post_id ); $web_res  = wp_remote_get( $web_link ) if ( ! is_wp_error( $web_res ) ) {  $item['body'] = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $web_res ); }
